# Найти вхождения строк в DataFrame по сравнению значения, полученного регулярным выражением

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть структура DataFrame, в которой хранится таблица с уязвимостями (много столбцов с различной информацией, такой как Идентификатор, Наименование, Версия ПО и т.д.).

Нужно отобрать определенные строки этой таблицы (вхождения по условиям).
Например, значение столбца "Версия ПО" в конкретной строке -

> "от 4.4.10 до 4.4.55 включительно (Linux), до 2.40.11 включительно (librsvg)".

Нужно вычленить значение версии, относящейся к (Linux), и сравнить её с конкретной (например с 4.4.54), а также запомнить это строку и записать её в новый DataFrame, если по результатам сравнения она проходит проверку (то есть наша версия 4.4.54 подвержена этой уязвимости).

Пока что смог реализовать поиск по простому вхождению конкретно описанного условия

```
vul_dataset = pd.read_excel(vul_base)

result_set = vul_dataset[
                    (vul_dataset['Версия ПО'].str.contains(r'(\d+.\d+.?\d+)\D+\(Linux\)', regex=True)
]
```

Но .str.contains возвращает True/False по простому соответствию, собственно вопрос - как добавить сравнение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь несколько вопросов. Первый - это достоверно выделить номера версий "от и до" из строк. Второй - сравнить выделенные версии с целевой.
Предложу в первом приближении вариант решения: с помощью `.str.extract()` выделяем в 2 столбца номера версий "от и до", которые превращаем в целые числа после удаления точек. Далее фильтруем df1 условием "версия больше или равна нижней границе и меньше или равна верхней границе", забираем индексы и отбираем нужные строки исходного фрейма.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Версия ПО': ['от 4.4.10 до 4.4.55 включительно (Linux), до 2.40.11 включительно (librsvg)',
                                 'от 4.4.10 до 4.4.40 включительно (Linux), до 2.40.11 включительно (librsvg)',
                                 'от 4.4.10 до 4.4.55 включительно (Unix), до 2.40.11 включительно (librsvg)']})
ver = '4.4.54'
ver = int(ver.replace('.',''))

df1 = df['Версия ПО'].str.extract(r'([\d.]+)\s+до\s+([\d.]+).+?Linux').replace('\.', '', regex=True).dropna().astype(int)
df1 = df1[df1[0].le(ver) & df1[1].ge(ver)]
print(df.loc[df1.index,'Версия ПО'])
```

```
0    от 4.4.10 до 4.4.55 включительно (Linux), до 2...
Name: Версия ПО, dtype: object
```

Comment: Использовал конструкцию из первого варианта Вашего решения, спасибо! А существует ли возможность с помощью .str.extract() забрать несколько вхождений в строке и, если одно из них пройдет по условиям фильтрации, забрать индекс этой строки? Например строка "от 0.1 до 0.5, от 1.2 до 1.3, от 1.5 до 1.6" соответствует нужной мне версии 1.3, но .str.extract(regex) заберет только 0.1 и 0.5 и фильтрацию они не пройдут